# Flutter app does not come to foreground when tapped on native android background service notification

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter, dart

I am new to learning flutter. My flutter app has a native android background service on kotlin where I have a socket running and whenever the socket listens to something I generate a notification using NotificationCompat.Builder.

But I am unable to bring the Flutter app back to foreground when ever the user taps on the notification.

I have tried creating a pendingintent and passing it to notificationbuilder setContentIntent() but nothing happens on tap.

shownotification function on Native background service:

```
fun shownotification (){
   packageNamer = this.getPackageName()
   launchIntent = this.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
   var className = launchIntent?.getComponent()!!.className.javaClass
   intent.action = "SELECT_NOTIFICATION"

   intent.setClass(this,className)
   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

    var builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "notifications")
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Much longer text that cannot fit one line...")
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
            .bigText("Much longer text that cannot fit one line..."))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)

    manager?.notify(456,builder.build())

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

<!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
     calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
     In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
     additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
     FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:label="bizzyb_demo"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <service android:name=".MyService" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
             until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
             there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
             defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
            android:value="true" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

What am I doing wrong here. I believe I am missing something very obvious here as I am new to mobile apps development.

Your expert feedbacks will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK` as a "Custom data" key-value-pair in the notification payload.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(Constants.EXAM_ID,String.valueOf(lectureDownloadStatus.getExamId()));

var builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "notifications")
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Much longer text that cannot fit one line...")
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
            .bigText("Much longer text that cannot fit one line..."))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setExtras(bundle) // Set the bundle
```

Comment: I should tell you I am not using push notification, I listening to socket events and generating notifications from them. Do I still need to set click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK ?

Comment: Anyway I have tried to add click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK using bundles, does not work.
<br/>
`var bundle:Bundle? = null <br/>
bundle?.putString("click_action","FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK ")` <br/>
@Vineet